# How can I round a QWidgets corners?

Tags: c++, qt

I am trying to round the corners of the current widget, but it doesnt work, why?

```
PopupWindow::PopupWindow() : QWidget(0) {
    setWindowFlags(
        Qt::Tool |
        Qt::FramelessWindowHint |
        Qt::WindowSystemMenuHint |
        Qt::WindowStaysOnTopHint
    );
    this->resize(300, 100);
    setStyleSheet(".PopupWindow {border-style: outset;border-width: 10px;border-radius:10px;}");

    QPushButton *hello = new QPushButton("Hello world!");
    hello->setFont(QFont("Times", 18, QFont::Bold));
    hello->setGeometry(10, 40, 180, 40);
    hello->setStyleSheet("");


    QVBoxLayout *layout = new QVBoxLayout;
    layout->addWidget(hello);
    setLayout(layout);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`border-radius` is not supported by QWidget (`border-style` and `border-width` are). Check out [the documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/stylesheet-reference.html#list-of-properties). Different widgets support a different subset of CSS properties.

Comment: This is for a Window (not a widget inside a parent window)? You would need to disable the window frame, enable transparency, and then set a mask for the window with a rounded border. I might be able to find the code I used years ago to do this...

Answer (score 2):

border-radius is supported by QFrame, you could also set a background color among other properties configurable by a style sheet.

So I think the design part that requires a radius in the border could be a QFrame instead of a QWidget.

Answer (score 0):

I added in the constructor:

`setAttribute(Qt::WA_TranslucentBackground);`

and then a new method:

```cpp
void MyWidget::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *event)
{
    QPainter painter(this);
    painter.setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing); // smooth borders
    painter.setBrush(QBrush(Qt::darkGray)); // visible color of background
    painter.setPen(Qt::transparent); // thin border color
    
    // Change border radius
    QRect rect = this->rect();
    rect.setWidth(rect.width()-1);
    rect.setHeight(rect.height()-1);
    painter.drawRoundedRect (rect, 15, 15);

    QWidget::paintEvent(event);
}
```